# Why does the PL330 always trigger a RX Timeout when reading?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, dma

we are using a CycloneV FPGA system with an integrated ARM Cortex-A9 dual core processor system. This processor system is running angstrom linux with a 4.1 kernel and has a pl330 DMA core. We are trying to write a kernel module to use this DMAC to push data into the FPGA fabric and read from it.

Writing to the FPGA works (albeit pretty slow), but everytime we try to read I can see the read transfer taking place, but the linux dmaengine reports a timeout and on kernel-level, the transfer is never finished.

Does somebody know why this might happen? I can comment out the timeout logic and get data out of it, so I'm guessing it might have to do with cache-coherency or something similar.

This is the read function in our kernel module:

```
static int dma_start_rx(struct platform_device *pdev, unsigned datalen, unsigned char *databuf, u32 burst_size, bool isDecrypt) {
  struct mRiddler_dev *pdata = platform_get_drvdata(pdev);
  struct dma_chan *dmaChan;
  struct dma_slave_config dmaConf;
  struct dma_async_tx_descriptor *dmaDesc = NULL;

  dmaChan = pdata->dma_rx_chan;
  memset(&dmaConf, 0, sizeof(dmaConf)); // Clear memory for DMA config

  // Build DMA configuration
  dmaConf.direction = DMA_DEV_TO_MEM;

  if (isDecrypt)
    dmaConf.src_addr = pdata->dma_datareg_phy + RID_DMA_DATA_READ_DECRYPT;
  else
    dmaConf.src_addr = pdata->dma_datareg_phy + RID_DMA_DATA_READ_ENCRYPT;

  #ifdef DEBUG
  pr_info("Accessing device address: %u, based on dma_datareg_phy: %u\n", dmaConf.src_addr, pdata->dma_datareg_phy);
  #endif

  dmaConf.src_addr_width = 8;
  dmaConf.src_maxburst = burst_size;

  pdata->dma_rx_addr = dma_map_single(&pdev->dev, databuf, datalen, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

  // Error handling
  if (dma_mapping_error(&pdev->dev, pdata->dma_rx_addr)) {
    pr_err("dma_map_single for RX failed!\n");
    return -EINVAL;
  }

  // Setup slave config
  dmaengine_slave_config(dmaChan, &dmaConf);

  // Get DMA descriptor
  dmaDesc = dmaengine_prep_slave_single(dmaChan, pdata->dma_rx_addr, datalen, dmaConf.direction, DMA_PREP_INTERRUPT);

  // Error handling
  if (!dmaDesc) {
    dma_shutdown(pdata);
    return -ENOMEM;
  }

  // Set callbacks
  dmaDesc->callback = dma_rx_done;
  dmaDesc->callback_param = pdata;

  // Get cookie and submit transfer to queue
  pdata->dma_rx_cookie = dmaengine_submit(dmaDesc);

  // Error handling
  if (dma_submit_error(pdata->dma_rx_cookie)) 
    pr_err("RX cookie error on dmaengine_submit\n");

  #ifdef DEBUG
  pr_info("Issueing RX transfer to DMA engine...\n");
  #endif

  // Start DMA
  dma_async_issue_pending(dmaChan);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Here's where the timeout is set up and the DMA read function is called:

```
if (numBytes > 0) {

    #ifdef DEBUG
    pr_info("Calling dma_start_rx with following values: numBytes=%d, burstSize=%d\n", numBytes, burstSize);
    #endif

    retVal = dma_start_rx(pdata->pdev, numBytes, pdata->dma_rx_buffer, burstSize, false);

    if (retVal) {
      pr_err("Error starting RX DMA!\n");
      return retVal;
    }

    if (!wait_for_completion_timeout(&dma_read_complete, msecs_to_jiffies(timeout))) {
      pr_err("Timeout while waiting for RX DMA\n");
      dmaengine_terminate_all(pdata->dma_rx_chan);
      return -ETIMEDOUT;
    }

    *offset = 0;
  }
```

This is the dmesg output when I try to read from the device:

```
[  326.486364] Issueing DMA transfer...
[  326.489952] DMA TX transfer finished!
[  335.607286] There are 4 words available in enc_tx FIFO!
[  335.612497] DMA read 32 > requested bytes 16, adjusting...
[  335.617992] Now reading 16 bytes in 2 words!
[  335.622246] Adjusted burstSize/numWords, new values: 2 and 2
[  335.627898] Calling dma_start_rx with following values: numBytes=16, burstSize=2
[  335.635283] Accessing device address: 3221225480, based on dma_datareg_phy: 3221225472
[  335.643168] Issueing RX transfer to DMA engine...
[  336.643795] Timeout while waiting for RX DMA, cookie: 2
```

Comment: where exactly in  your code you recieve timeout error, and what exactly dmesg show at that moment?

Comment: I added the relevant code to the original post. Dmesg isn't showing anything but the messages my module prints. I added those prints to the post as well

Comment: so, how you calculate timeout value to pass to`wait_for_completion_timeout` , and why you sure that  timeout is big enough?

Comment: The timeout value is a module parameter and is set to 1000ms. I can see that the transfer is finished much earlier than that in the FPGA fabric.

Comment: And if you replace your dma transfer with `read(b|w|l)` in cycle how fast it would be?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but it takes about 20 FPGA cycles (at 50 MHz that's 400ns) for the transfer to complete. I think that leaves more than enough time for the processor.

If I remove the timeout requirement, copying data finishes, but the data is not in the target file. If I then do another read, it does no longer reach the FPGA, but the target file is filled with correct data. That's why I think it's some kind of cache problem.

Comment: Why your burst size is 2? I don't know cyclone, but fpga should be connected with arm cpu via 32bit bus, so it should be at least 4?

Comment: Burst size is 2 in this case, because I didn't read more data in that call. If I read more data, the burst size is bigger (up to 16), but that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: `src_addr_width = 8;` So, you are trying to read 8 bytes at once. Does your hardware support that?

Comment: Yes, it uses 64bit words and a 64bit bridge

Comment: Either you have a hardware bug, or you misconfigured DMA engine. hte timeout means no interrupt came from DMA controller. I saw this (on the different type of DMA engine) many times due to misconfiguration (addresses, bus widths, transfer widths (burst), etc.

Comment: I guess I'll have to try around then. Thanks for helping!

Comment: After a lot of trying around, I still don't have a solution, but some weird behavior: If I remove the timeout requirement from the kernel module and run a read request, the read callback function is called with the next write access (after the write access has called its callback). Any thoughts about that?